# How to define the interval of integration to calculate a joint probability

Tags: probability, joint-distribution

So, I have a **really** basic question (I guess) of how to definite the interval of integration to calculate a probability in a joint density function.

I want to calculate $P(x > y+1)$ for the joint density bellow

$$Fxy (x, y) = \frac1{64} (x+y),\ 0<x<4,\ 0<y<4$$

The solution is bellow and I cannot understand how to arrive to these intervals. $$P(x > y+1) = \int_{1}^{4} \int_{0}^{x-1} \frac1{64} (x+y) dydx$$

Comment: To have $x \gt y+1$ when $0 \lt x \lt 4$ and $0 \lt x \lt 4$ then (a) you need $y \gt 0$ and $y \lt \min(4,x-1)$ and (b) $x \gt \max(y+1,0) \ge \max(1,0)$ and $x \lt 4$

Comment: You are invoking *Fubini's Theorem;* it's often easiest to work out by sketching the graph of the integration region; and this is the subject matter of textbooks on integral Calculus--it's not special to probability or statistics.  This ought to give you some keywords and guidance for learning more about this technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plot the region of support, i.e. $[0,4]\times[0,4]$ and the boundary line $x=y+1$, the region of integration will be the intersection of the region to the left of this line and the region of support. As also pointed out in the comments, the rest is calculus stuff actually. You first define an order of integration; here it is $dy dx$, which means the outer integral have limits corresponding to all $x$ in this region, and the inner integral limits will correspond to $y$ when $x$ is fixed.

The region of integration starts from $x=1$ and ends at $x=4$. So, the limits are from $1$ to $4$. Now, you let $x$ be a constant in this range, then $y$ starts from $0$ to the line, where $y=x-1$.